# Detecting regular expression in content during parse

Tags: javascript, c++, perl, language-agnostic, parsing

I am writing a simple parser for C. I was just running it with some other language files (for fun - to see the extent of C-likeness and laziness - don't wanna really write separate parsers for each language if I can avoid it).

However the parser seems to break down for JavaScript if the code  being parsed contains regular expressions...

Case 1:
For example, while parsing the JavaScript code snippet,

```
var phone="(304)434-5454"
phone=phone.replace(/[\(\)-]/g, "") 
//Returns "3044345454" (removes "(", ")", and "-")
```

The '(', '[' etc get matched as starters of new scopes, which may never be closed.

Case 2:
And, for the Perl code snippet,

```
 # Replace backslashes with two forward slashes
 # Any character can be used to delimit the regex
 $FILE_PATH =~ s@\\@//@g;
```

The // gets matched as a comment...

How can I detect a regular expression within the content text of a "C-like" program-file?

Comment: Why do you care if the string with which you're doing the match contains regex operator characters? You don't execute regex patterns from input, your execute them _on_ your input.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to parse, and into what?  And why would `//` get flagged as a comment in Perl?  Parsers are normally written for a defined language.

Comment: @David Thornley: The parser is written for C.

Comment: Thanks for the edits.  They improve the question greatly.  However, I still don't know why you'd want to do this.  A C parser is complicated as it is, and trying to make it detect regular expressions from other languages will make it even more complicated and perhaps cause it to misparse some C.  I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: > why you'd want to do this? 
laziness. ;) Don't really want to write separate parsers for each language, there is much overlap! I was surprised that the C-parser works reasonably well for C# and Java (because all I'm doing is symbol identification)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible.

Take this, for example:

```
m =~ s/a/b/g;
```

Could be both C or perl.

One minute's thinking reveals, that the number of perl style regular expressions that are also sntyctically valid C expressions is infinite.

Another example:

```
m+foo *bar[index]+i
```

The best you can get is some extreme vague guesswork. The difficulty stems from the fact that a regular expression is a sequence of characters that can be virtually everything.

You better clean up your error handling. A parser should not "break down" if some parenthesis are missing or superfluous ones are seen.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your token grammar has to take regex syntax into consideration.  Classic parsers consist of two layers: something to *tokenize* the input, and then something to parse the grammar.  The syntax of the language is generally expressed in terms of *tokens*, so the job of the tokenizer is to feed a stream of those to the parser. Generally the tokens them selves are regular expressions, or more properly a great big regex of things ORed together. At each character position on the input, one of the token regexes must match or else the character is invalid.

Now, there are other parsing techniques that sort-of squish together the tokenization with the parsing.  ("PEG" parsers for example)

**edit** — another note: you can't parse languages like Javascript or Perl with just a regular expression.

Comment: I'm not trying to parse the languages with just a regular expression.

Comment: So I guess I'll have to use separate regex syntax for each language.

Comment: Yes, generally every language has its own rules for tokens, though sometimes they're boring enough to share.

Comment: I'll go one simpler: You can't parse Perl. Or, more precisely, you can't *statically* parse Perl. PPI comes pretty close, though. http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PPI#Background

Comment: @Michael Carman
How about JavaScript? Can it parsed statically?

Comment: @sonofdelphi: As far as I know JavaScript can be statically parsed. The key problem with Perl is how function prototypes change the way things are parsed.